# Execute code for specific character values.

Tags: c

I'm currently taking the Video Game Programming course at the Art Institute of Vancouver, in my second quarter and I have a programming class. I'm currently stuck on a bit of homework and I'm unsure why. I'm a beginner when it comes to programming. I have experience with HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The problem I have involves creating a bill for a telephone service customer, but it is entirely dependant on the type of service they are using. The code needs to be executed if the service code they input is either 'r' or 'p', and any other input results in an error. However I'm unsure where to proceed after this.

`

```
int account, minutes1, minutes2;
char s;
float cost; 


printf("Please enter your account number. \n");
scanf_s("%d" , &account);

if(account == -1)
    return 0;

printf("Please enter your service code(r for regular or p for premium). \n"); /*checking service*/
scanf_s(" %s" , &s);

switch(s)
{ /*execute specific parameters when r or p are selected as service codes.*/
case 'a':
case 'b':
case 'c':
case 'd':
case 'e':
case 'f':
case 'g':
case 'h':
case 'i':
case 'j':
case 'k':
case 'l':
case 'm':
case 'n':
case 'o': printf("Error. Please choose a correct service code (r for regular or p for premium). \n"); 
    break;
case 'p': printf("Please enter how many minutes you've used between 6am and 6pm. \n");
    scanf_s("%d" , &minutes1); 
    if(minutes1 > 75)
        minutes1 = (minutes1-75)*.10;
    printf("Please enter how many minutes you've used between 7pm and 5am. \n");
    scanf_s("%d" , &minutes2);
    if(minutes2 > 100)
        minutes2 = (minutes2-100)*.05;
    cost = 25+minutes1+minutes2;
    printf("Your account number is %d, your service code is premium, you used %d minutes during the day and %d minutes during the night and your bill comes to $%lf. \n", account, minutes1, minutes2, cost);
    break;
case 'q':
case 'r': printf("Please enter how many minutes you've used. \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &minutes1); 
    if(minutes1 > 55)
        minutes1 = (minutes1-55)*.20;
    cost = 10+minutes1;
    printf("Your account number is %d, your service code is regular, you used %d minutes and your bill comes to %lf. \n");
    break;
case 's':
case 't':
case 'u':
case 'v':
case 'w':
case 'x':
case 'y':
case 'z': printf("Error. Please choose a correct service code (r for regular or p for premium). \n"); 
    break;
}`
```

Comment: `scanf_s(" %s" , &s);` should be `scanf_s(" %c" , &s, 1);`

Comment: You should review your use of minutes1 and minutes2 variables, they are integers, but you are using them as result for storing double value. For example: `(minutes1-75)*.10` is double but when you assign it to minutes1 variable it gets converted to integer again, therefore you are losing information.

Comment: `case q:` is going to downfall into `case r` I do not think you want that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are scanning for character you should use scanf("%c",&s);

Also just use:

```
switch(s){
    case 'p':
         ...
         break;
    case 'r':
         ...
         break;
    default:
         error
}
```

Comment: are you sure about that? The code seems to be quite different for the two cases (p and r)

Comment: I've missed that. I just wanted to show default case.

Comment: I think the @gandgandi is trying to point out that the OP doesn't need to enumerate every case - cover your desired inputs (`p` and `r`), then use default to cover the rest as errors.

Comment: now it works. @wilcroft an answer must be correct. Mind reading is not supported on SO